# Error in R with Months as levels. Is this a bug or logic flaw?

Tags: r, dplyr, levels

Imagine a dataframe (this is an illustrative sample)

```
s <- c("January", "February", "March", "January", "March", "April")
t <- c(5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 7)
df1 <- as.data.frame(s)
df1[ , 2] <- t
```

Now for graphing purposes, I wanted to consolidate by month. If I write the code and then summarize:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1$s <- factor(df1$s, levels = month.name)
 summary <- df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(Sales = sum(V2))
```

The outputs are correct but out of order:

```
April     7
February  3
January   8
March     5
```

However, if I do the following:

```
df1$s <- as.factor(df1$s)
levels(df1$s) <- c("January", "February", "March", "April")
Summary <- df1 %>% group_by(s) %>% summarize(Sales = sum(V2))
```

The output are:

```
January    7
February   3
March      8
April      5
```

The sums are wrong but order is correct. Why would this be?

It's like it organizes by month alphabetically then resorts the Month column without changing the other values.

Comment: I get the correct order when I run your first code chunk. Though I assume you mean `group_by(s)` instead of `group_by(a)`.

Comment: Instead of overwriting, try `df1$s2 <- as.factor(df1$s); levels(df1$s2) <- c("January", "February", "March", "April")` and you'll see that you're misusing level assignment. Also, fyi, you might get confused with these var names, since `t` and `summary` are commonly-used builtin functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to relevel factor, you can use the `forcats` package and manipulate factor order. As you see in the end of this post, your factor order was not in the month order. So, I used `fct_relevel()` to change the level and did the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df1 %>%
mutate(s = fct_relevel(s, month.name[1:4])) %>%
group_by(s) %>%
summarise(Sales = sum(V2)) -> out

out

#             s Sales
#    <fctr> <dbl>
#1  January     8
#2 February     3
#3    March     5
#4    April     7

# Check level order

#levels(out$s)
#[1] "January"  "February" "March"    "April"

#levels(df1$s)
#[1] "April"    "February" "January"  "March"
```